# "Failed to load resource" using Facebook's example code

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to run the first example from the documentation of the Facebook JS SDK.  I created a new app, created a blank document called "facebookTest.html", pasted in the code from the example, and plugged in the new app's App ID.  Code as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login with facebook</title>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'my app ID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
      status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

  };

  // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
  // Note that the debug version is being actively developed and might 
  // contain some type checks that are overly strict. 
  // Please report such bugs using the bugs tool.
  (function(d, debug){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = document.location.protocol+"//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document, /*debug*/ false));
</script>
```

When I load the page, on the Javascript console I get the following error message:

`Failed to load resource`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: When I add `document.location.protocol` before the `"//connect.facebook.net/..."`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9849572/619177), the screen stays blank, and the console shows the following:

```
GET file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
```

Is that all this code is supposed to do?  Or is it still failing?

Comment: Check your AdBlock! :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There were a couple things wrong here:

1. needed to change `js.src` assignment to:
   `js.src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";`
2. Facebook no longer supports JS SDK calls made from a local file, the script has to be run on a file with an `http://` or `https://` URI, as per [this bug report on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/165982843535513/).  I will need to upload the file to a web server, change the canvas URL accordingly, and retest.

Comment: IN explanation to pointer 2. This is because the `js.src` in init code is protocol relative. so if you are accessing a local file. it will try to access fb sdk over file: and the error

Comment: Yes, I found that I can test it on a local web server (e.g. WAMP) if I access the file as, e.g., `localhost/FacebookApp` instead of `file://c:\wamp\www\FacebookApp\index.html`.

Comment: Yes. That is because your js.src might be pointing to `"//connect.facebok.... ` it is protocol relative. therefore. if you are accessing ur page locally without server i.e. using a `file://` , so facebook init tries to load the javascript sdk from `file://connect.facebook.net.... ` which is not going to happen. So it does not work. 

Also.. it is best to have js.src point to `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js` so that even http requests are handled. Anyway.. I learned it today, So thought to share.

Comment: I had the same problem. But now when it should show the login form I get this error message: "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.
" Any idea on how to resolve that. I have the correct URL's in there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember to check your adblock! ;)

Answer (score 88):

just disable adblock, 
it works for me

Comment: Hey, simple an best answer =)

Comment: Really is The Adblock chrome extensions blocks it, thanks.

Comment: In firefox, you'll need to disable facebook container and tracking protection

Comment: Does this mean facebook login won't work if people have adblock enabled?

Comment: @workwise it was true few years ago, idk about current siatuation, but it is possible to be an true.

Comment: that's it. add blockers are designed to stop trackers and ad services like facebook and google.

Answer (score 6):

First you need to append http or https to js.src url

Second you need to host you html file on a server.

Answer (score 4):

If your URL contains words such as "advert", "ad", "doubleclick", "click", or something similar…

*For example:*

- `GET googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id`
- `static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js`

…Then ad-blocker will block it.

Ref : [Getting "net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT" error on some AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341765/getting-neterr-blocked-by-client-error-on-some-ajax-calls/32916582)

Answer (score 0):

Go To Facebook developer and add your website domain and get the id and paste below:

```
 appId : 'my app ID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more thing I didn't see here: if you are debugging in Firefox, disable Enhanced Tracking Protection and Facebook Container while you are developing.

Answer (score 0):

just disable any kind of ad blocker extention you have use then it will be working fine.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32856286)

Answer (score 0):

Worth to check any kind of ad blocker extension.
The error `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` is exactly about it.

There are several solutions you can try to fix this error:

- Solution 1: Disable extensions
- Solution 2: Whitelist the domain
- Solution 3: Debug the issue
- Solution 4: Clear browser cache and cookies#
- Solution 5: Disable antivirus software
- Solution 6: Use Incognito mode

Here is a full article about it:
https://www.keycdn.com/support/how-to-solve-err-blocked-by-client