# facebook login button does not show up on my page

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, button, authentication

I have included the code i needed to be able to show the facebook login button on my page. But the button does not show up, could you please read my code and tell me if you see any problems with it? Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      vappId            : '486506335043368',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.10'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src =                             "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=486506335043368";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-    button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-    link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Check the browser console. And are you testing this in a page you call via HTTP/HTTPS in your browser - or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Failed to load resource" using Facebook's example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669167/failed-to-load-resource-using-facebooks-example-code)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 possible problems:

1)You need to change js.src assignment to: `js.src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";`

2)I think Facebook does not support calls from a local file, the script has to be run on a file with an http:// or https:// URI.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15747913/4360136).